# django run a daemon?

Tags: python, django, daemon

I would like to recreate some data in my project every 30 minutes (prices that change). also I got another job that needs to refresh every minute.
Now I heard I should use a daemon. but I'm not sure how that works.
Can someone put me into the right direction.

Also should i make an extra model to save that temporary data or is that part of the daemon?

PS: not sure if stack overflow can be used for this sort of questions, but i don't know where to search for this sort of information

Comment: I just searched for "django daemon" on Google - the first link was [an answer on StackOverflow...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156470/how-to-run-own-daemon-processes-with-django)

Comment: im not sure, i noticed that one, but as said there as well, aint that an overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a daemon. You just want cron jobs.

The best thing to do is to write your scripts as [custom Django management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands/) and use cron to trigger them to run at the specified intervals.