# ADB Command Weird Behavior

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have a question regarding ADB.

I'm sorry about the title of this question as I really don't know how to put a good title to this.

I'm working with many android devices at the moment, and I noticed that on some devices, the following problem occurs.

Say I want to run a shell script (my_script.sh) that is located in the /data/local/tmp/ folder of the phone.

If I do this:

```
adb shell 'sh /data/local/tmp/my_script.sh &'
```

nothing happens on the phone.

If I just go into adb shell (by entering adb shell on a terminal) and when I get this prompt:

```
shell@android:/ $
```

and then I type in the following:

```
sh /data/local/tmp/my_script.sh &
```

everything works just fine.

This happens on only a few of the devices I have. So I'm not able to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Here is another piece of information that might help someone. If I don't use the "&"  at the end (which means I don't run the script in a background process), everything works as well.

The following code gives the correct behavior:

```
adb shell 'sh /data/local/tmp/my_script.sh'
```

I'm completely lost, and I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: So this issue has puzzled me for a while, and I spent quite a bit of time investigating this issue. I've noticed another behavior, say I lock the screen (by pressing the power key) and then issue the command:

```
adb shell 'sh /data/local/tmp/my_script.sh &'
```

And then unlock the screen, the script will run fine.

This is really the weirdest thing I've encountered in a long time.

I really hope someone can lend a hand here.

Comment: Are there any consistencies amongst the devices it doesn't work on? Are they all the same API Version or Manufacturer?

Comment: Hello Corey, Thanks for the quick reply. Yeah, the two devices that do not work are both Samsung devices. How can I check the API version ?

Comment: There's a table [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)

Comment: Why are you attempting to run the script in the background? Just run the whole adb command in the background, otherwise closing adb connection will close script's stdin/out/err and may cause it to fail.

Comment: Hello dtmilano, by running the whole adb command in the command, do you mean something like adb shell 'sh /data/local/tmp/my_script.sh' & ?

Comment: If that is what you meant, I don't think that will work for my purpose. I forgot to mention that I need to be able to start the script and then unplug the USB cable. If I do  "adb shell 'xxxxxxx' &", the script will not run after I unplug the usb.

Comment: If you want to be able to disconnect the cable you need something like setsid to change the process group id rather than leave it tied to the parent shell which will die with the cable pull.  And maybe to do something about the streams  too.  And you may need a wakelock.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to daemonize some program to run in the background. But normally the child process will got killed while the parent is gone. In this case, your adb shell is the parent process.

And this behavior is really different from device to device. I just tried it on my phone and found that "&" didn't take any effect, the shell command is still blocked.

I think a better way to handle it is to use standard daemonize approach of linux. Please refer to:

1. [Write a daemonize native program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux)
2. [How to daemonize  a script on a generic linux os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525247/how-do-i-daemonize-an-arbitrary-script-in-unix)