# How to play short mp3 file in python script in the background (Daemon) repeatedly?

Tags: python, mp3, daemon

I use linux, e.g. Pepermint OS. There is a mysql table, there is numeric field as a flag.  The table only has 1 record. If the field contain 1, I want to play a short mp3 once an then update the field to 0/zero again. There is an application that can play mp3 from command prompt, e.g mpg123.

To play the mp3, I use the following script :

```
import subprocess
call = "mpg123 ting_tong1.mp3 & "
p = subprocess.Popen( call, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I want the script run in the background, like a service in Windows. I have been trying night and day with several daemon library in python, but no luck.

There should a music sound e.g. the mp3 sound, every time the field changed from 0 to 1 !

The daemon run but the music only run once :( .  How to do that ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [nohup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423550/7062162) command to start a daemon process and the [watch](https://superuser.com/a/361919) command to repeat the command after a specified time.

`call = "watch -n0 nohup mpg123 ting_tong1.mp3 &"`

You can add `>out.txt` `2>err.txt`, otherwise std output and error is stored in a file called nohup.out

Comment: Nohup ? Oh let me try, Thank's for your answer !

Comment: It work !. Thank you ! Although I have't test with the field flag, but I can hear the sound repeatedly ! Yet after I close all terminal windows ! You save my time !