# What is the equivalent of "&" from shell script in python

Tags: python, linux, function, shell

I have a script written this way on shell script

```
function test1(){ command1 };
function test2(){ command2 };
function test3(){ command3 };
```

I use the `&` on shell script to run those functions daemonized writting `test1 & test2 & test3`

But I want to do the same thing on Python. Is there a way to do it using any of python built-in functions and not using the "daemonize" library?

EDIT: I think I should have written it better. I can see now that "background" is the better word for the question. My intention was to join what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525247/how-do-i-daemonize-an-arbitrary-script-in-unix) with the python command to make something daemonized-like.
[tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47421967/8992327) already answer it for me.

Thank everybody who left a comment and sorry for the mistake.

I can't give points or add a comment since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: What do you mean by daemonize? Would you like them to continue to execute after the python script execution is over? Or just execute in parallel?

Comment: Daemonizing a script is different than simply running it in the background (which is what `&` does).

Comment: You could use threads. It's not exactly the same thing but should accomplish the same goal and is as close as you're going to get using Python.

Answer (score 0):

The Python [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) allows you to run several processes simultaneously, just like the shell's background jobs.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Process(target=test1, args=('bob',))
    t1.start()
    t2 = Process(target=example2)
    t2.start()
    t3 = Process(target=demo3, args=('steve jobs', 'bill gates'))
    t3.start()
    # ... Do other stuff
```

... where `test1`, `example2`, and `demo3` are Python functions you want to run concurrently with your main / parent process.

If you don't want to run Python code in parallel, `subprocess.Popen()` creates a process running an external command independently of your Python program.