# How to stop flask in bash

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script to automate running my flask app:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                           

python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate

export FLASK_APP=my_app
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

I'd like to change it to `flask run &` so that I can close the tab and still have it running, but I don't know how to stop the app if I've done it in this way.  If I'm in a new tab and a new environment, what would I have to do to stop the app?

Comment: try something like this to see the PID: `ps aux | grep flask` then you can kill that PID.

Comment: Use: Gunicorn, uWSGI, Gevent, or Twisted Web

Answer (score 0):

To stop the process is necessary to keep the pid somewhere and then kill it.
You could keep the pid like this:

```
./your-script.sh &
echo $! > save_pid.txt
```

Then if you want to kill the process:

```
kill $(cat save_pid.txt)
rm save_pid.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Linux / OS X etc.

One way to do it to "exec" the flask task in the bash script after recording the bash's PID for example:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                           

python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate

export FLASK_APP=my_app
export FLASK_ENV=development
echo $$ > $HOME/.my_app.pid

exec flask run
```

Then you can check the contents of `$HOME/.my_app.pid` to know which pid to kill

The `exec` makes bash simply execute the flask run command replacing its own pid (the bash disappears)

The more interesting approach would be to use `daemonize` ... This is answered in details here:

[How do I daemonize an arbitrary script in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525247/how-do-i-daemonize-an-arbitrary-script-in-unix)

Hopefully this helps.